# How are the pixels placed in an int[] array of pixels when getting pixels from a Android Bitmap?

Tags: android, arrays, image, bitmap

I really need to know some detail about bitmap.getPixels(...), that the documentation does not say. I want to know how are the pixels displayed in the int[] array. Is it row after row or column after column?

To be more specifi:

```
imagine image: [0,0][0,1][0,2][0,3]
               [1,0][1,1][1,2][1,3]
array looks like this?: [0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3]
or it looks like this?: [0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1],[0,2],[1,2]...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter of getPixels function (int stride),  is necessary to say at the function how many pixels there are for each row. So the function know that after X pixels have to skip at new row.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) you can find the documentation!

Comment: Hmm..I must admit that I did not fully understand what 'skip between rows' actually mean. U made it clear! Thanks ;)